# Sink P-Trap doesn't line up with Drain pipe

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

How can I get my sink drain lined up properly. The drain coming out of the wall is welded together and it doesn't have the connector that catches the threaded side of the p-trap. It's' also about an inch short from the p-trap. Thanks for the help guys. [image: pics]
[image: pic2]

Comment: Not welded, soldered.

Comment: It could be JB Weld at the slip joint.  Not sure if it makes a difference, though.

Answer (score 4):

OK as a temp fix you could:

- cut the existing metal tube, leave at least a couple inches from the blobbed up old connection.
- clean the outside of the tube as well as you can, I would probably use steel wool.
- use an 1 1/2" slip-joint coupler:

[image][image]

- connect the new trap with the arm it came with, into the coupler.

Answer (score 2):

The cluster-*bleep* solder job at the end of the chromed pipe should not be there at all. You or a plumber will be unsoldering that mess (possibly one joint back, at the Tee) and replacing it with the right parts - which are a compression fitting similar to the one you have on the trap, allowing a proper slip-joint adjustable positioning of the replacement for the chromed pipe, with the correct nut to join to the trap.

If you opt to do it yourself, be sure to wrap the other legs of the Tee with damp rags to keep them from becoming unsoldered as you remove the middle leg.

Comment: +1 I agree with this answer except that, like @Edwin, I am not convinced that the F'd up joint in question is "welded" (soldered). It looks like it may have had an 1 1/2" slip-joint fitting at one time but has since been insulted with various applications of putty/epoxy etc.

Comment: I just want it to drain. I will have to have a professional plumber fix it later. In the meantime what can I do to make it work.. Thanks again for all the help guys.

Comment: The answer is what's needed to make it drain. Either that, or dig up the sink that this was kludged onto before. If you can't adjust the slip joint because an idiot ruined it, you can't have a sink with the hole an inch different from the old sink (or a trap an inch different from the old trap) and in any case you are missing the nut. If, in fact, the slip joint is merely a blob of putty, you might be able to pull the thing out another inch and wrap it with self-fusing rubber tape, as a purely temporary fix that may drip. If it's solder or epoxy that probably won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid getting into the metal pipe at all, just put in a horizontal run immediately off the sink basket, like you'd see with a double sink. I did exactly that with my utility sink recently to accommodate a poorly-located wye at the stack. Parts are cheap and readily available.

Imagine this scenario without the disposal branch on the right:

[image]

Turn down again into your trap. This will give you much more flexibility to align with your metal pipe. The trap will come into it from one side or the other, depending on how you prefer your layout.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why you can't loosen the nut on the pvc pipe and turn it to line up under the pipe?  I've done it on two occasions.

Comment: I suspect you're commenting on the optical illusion in the second picture.  That one looks like you could simply rotate the PVC pipe.  If you look at the first picture, you'll see the gap described in the question.